# Multiple sensor data to WiFi visualized on React Native app: Guidance

Tags: mechanical-engineering, computer-engineering, wifi, iot

**Objective:** I want to connect multiple sensors to an item of equipment and visualize the data real-time on an iPad.

**Mock of Desired Output:**[image]

**Question:** I need advice on the best methods to use to connect multiple sensor data and transfer the data through either wifi or Bluetooth.

Should I use / Is it possible to use Arduino (I have experience with this)

Are there existing wifi modules that allow for such a connection between multiple sensors and devices?

**Considerations**

- I have experience with Reactjs and react native to build the application
- Sensors are (RPM, flow rate, weight, and PSI)
- This is pretty vague but I'm new to the IoT and acknowledge it will be a challenge.

Comment: The simplest method is to use a wifi based system. Use MQTT or Restful to connect sensor to the cloud. Arduino is good place to start. Check out https://io.adafruit.com/ this might be a good place to start.

Comment: While an interesting question, it's overly broad and not a good fit for the StackExchange Q&A model.